# passing product info to another product

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

We have a commerce site that provides samples of its items. We have a single product that handles all the samples and displays them in a dropdown.  What I'd like to do is have a link on the product page that passes this product name/slug to the sample product. What would be the best way to approach this?

The sample product url is /samples/sample. I have tried something like Order a Sample. But that tries to look up a product with that url and it does not exist.

In the dropmenu I am trying

```
{% set prodSlug = craft.request.getLastSegment() %} 
<select>
{% for purchasable in product.variants %}
    {% set current = (product.slug == prodSlug) %}
       {% if current %} 
        <option {% if purchasable.stock <= 0 and purchasable.hasUnlimitedStock == false %}disabled {% endif %} value="{{ purchasable.id }}">
        {{ purchasable.description }}  {{ purchasable.price|commerceCurrency(cart.currency) }}</option>
       {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Is there a way to setup a product that could accept different slugs to make this work? Maybe with a route?

Answer (score 1):

Yep so can just create a route in the control panel.

See: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/routing.html

You'll see you can use a slug (using the token `slug`) so that Craft will validate the url actually has a valid slug on the end, or you can just use `*` and craft will route to this template no matter what is on the end.

[image]

(I personally prefer to create routes in source control managed & commented code using the `routes.php` config file - https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/routing.html#advanced-routing-with-url-rules  ... so this would be something like:

`'samples/sample/<slug>'          => ['template' => '/your/samples/template']`

Then, on the main product page, build your url to the samples page as, basically:

`/samples/sample/{{ thisProduct.slug }}`

Then, in your samples template you just grab the last segment, as you are, and use that in your code to pre-select the particular sample from you list...as you are.

So basically, you're almost there apart from creating the route.